# Java AWT fillOval() not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I'm working on a program that draws a graph, so I would like to draw points! I'd like the points to be circular since that's usually how points are represented, and to the best of my knowledge, `g2.fillOval(x, y, height, width)` should draw a filled oval with height `height` and width `width` at `(x, y)`. This is my code at the moment:

```
private void drawCenteredCircle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int radius) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setColor(pointColor);
    g2.fillOval(x-radius, y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

Which is then called in the `paintComponent()` method of a `JPanel`. It does draw, so I know the code is functioning, but for some reason, it draws a square, like so:
[my square oval :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15G83.png)

[image]

I also tried this:

```
private void drawCenteredCircle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int radius) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.setColor(pointColor);
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Float(x-radius, y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

But got the same result. Any help as to how to draw a filled circle/ellipse would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that without a decent [mcve], you're not going to get a decent answer. If time is of the essence, do look at that link and consider creating and posting one of these. Note also that all code should be posted here and not in a link.

Comment: Except perhaps this time your problem is due to RenderingHints not being set properly. Test it out.

Comment: No code was posted in a link, that was an image of what my result looked like. Also, thanks for the minimal, complete, and verifiable example page, I'll be sure to read through that and post questions using that format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to set your Graphic2D's RenderingHints to handle aliasing. This smooths out the jaggies that may be causing your (small) circle to render as a square. Something like:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```